# Spring & mapstruct, generate a mapper using a parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, mapper

Mapstruct always generate mappers that use a default empty constructor and setters to construct an object.

I need mapstruct to construct objects using parameterized constructor instead.

I have this mapper configured using maptruct:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface FlightMapper {
    FlightBooking  flightBookingPostRequestDtoToFlightBooking(FlightBookingPostRequestDto flightBookingDto);
}
```

The implementation that mapstruct generates uses the default constructor without parameters:

```
public FlightBooking flightBookingPostRequestDtoToFlightBooking(FlightBookingPostRequestDto     flightBookingDto) {
    if ( flightBookingDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    FlightBooking flightBooking = new FlightBooking();

    flightBooking.setFlight_booking_id( flightBookingDto.getBooking_id() );

    return flightBooking;
}
```

But I need this implementation with a parameterized constructor instead:

```
public FlightBooking flightBookingPostRequestDtoToFlightBooking(FlightBookingPostRequestDto    flightBookingDto) {
    if ( flightBookingDto == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    FlightBooking flightBooking = new FlightBooking(flightBookingDto.getBooking_id());

    return flightBooking;
}
```

How can I configure mapstruct to achieve this? I haven't found any responses in the official documentation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1.4 release, MapStruct supports using constructors when instantiating mapping targets.

One solution would be marking the parametrized constructor as `@Default`. For more possible solutions and more details on how the Constructor support works have a look at the [reference guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-with-constructors).

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectFactory](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/ObjectFactory.html) is the way to go.

> By default beans are created during the mapping process with the
> default constructor. If a factory method with a return type that is
> assignable to the required object type is present, then the factory
> method is used instead.
>
> Factory methods can be defined ***without parameters, with an @TargetType
> parameter, a @Context parameter, or with the mapping source parameter***.
> If any of those parameters are defined, then the mapping method that
> is supposed to use the factory method needs to be declared with an
> assignable result type, assignable context parameter, and/or
> assignable source types.

I left to you the pleasure of reading documentation and solve the problem :)